# Cocos2d for iOS: show EULA in PDF or PNG

Tags: ios, pdf, cocos2d-iphone, eula

I would like to [show an EULA in my Cocos2d app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894228/showing-eula-when-app-starts-and-quiting-if-user-doesnt-accept-it) Is there any recommended way in Cocos2d and if so could you guide me to some tutorial? It is a one page document which fits perfectly in a PDF - is there any way to show a PDF on a Cocos2d App?

I tried adding a PNG file but I was not able to allow to "zoom in" with the pinch movements. Also PNG files are less resolution when compared to PDF.

Consideration: In both cases (PDF & PNG) the user will need to "pinch zoom" the image in order to be able to read the text properly. I am a bit afraid that this might put off the user as haven't found one iOS APP yet that does use this mechanism.

Comment: How about HTML page? Either local or from network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a EULA in your user's face is going to put them off. Ask yourself why no other iOS app does this.

At best apps add a hyperlink to their "terms of service" which will open in Safari when tapped, and perhaps a note that if you sign in, you agree. Check out the Game Center account creation process if you want an example on how to design this.

PDF or PNG are terrible ideas, display either a HTML webview or a simple text view.

Comment: These are all good points. Displaying your text as a PNG (or, to a lesser extent, as a PDF) just destroys accessibility, which is bad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that puts users off. I am afraid about legal sues on the game. Pheraphs I could display for short a page where I say "Facts in this game are fictional and music belongs to the respective authors (C) Copyright etc.." just to give a brief non off putting half second message.